# How to make use of a real PCI modem in a Virtual Machine?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware, pci

Is there a way where I can use my PCI modem in a virtual machine on an ubuntu 12.04 host box? I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on the host and I want to use my PCI modem on a guest virtual machine. Can this be done using kvm, vmware or virtualbox?

Update:

I have tried this https://askubuntu.com/questions/16586/how-to-access-serial-ubuntu-host-serial-port-on-virtualbox-guest-os but i had no luck, I suspect it needs the drivers for the modem installed on the host.

Update 2:

It seems that if i want to use the PCI modem on the guest box without having the drivers on the host box Oracle PCI Passthrough is the eay to go: http://howtoware.blogspot.com/2012/01/oracle-vm-virtualbox-how-to-use-pci.html
:-(

Hardware details:

Ubuntu 12.04 x32

Agere PCI modem (Tested on a Windows 7 box and is working fine)

Comment: I have never tried this but is there any reason to expect that it won't? Why don't you try and then ask here if you have specific problems.

Comment: I have tested some stuff already without any luck but I asked this way because i might had gone for the wrong way. I haven't the Ubuntu 12.04 drivers for the modem so I'm really loose.... Can you please help?

Comment: In that case please explain what you have tried and how it is failing. I am not an expert, so I may very well be wrong, but as far as I know there is no reason for PCI modems to be special. Please [edit] your question and include the VM you are using, the guest OS, how you are checking whether the card is working, the hardware details of the card etc.

Comment: Yes, use PCI passthrough. I’m using USB passthrough with kvm for a Simtec EntropyKey with great success, but you must remember that it is absolutely important that the *host* system does *not* use the device, i.e. you *must* blacklist the driver for it on your host system (at least that was enough for USB; for PCI, maybe more is needed; consult the documentation on PCI passthrough). – Another option is to use the drivers in the host, and pass the modem through as virtual COM: (serial port) device; no idea if that’s what helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to use PCI pass-through on VirtualBox is dicey, it's still an experimental feature.  Your hardware needs to support IOMMU which is uncommon in consumer-grade equipment.

The host OS needs to recognize the device and create a serial port for it, /dev/ttyS? or /dev/ttyUSB? or any of a series of other options depending on the distribution.

If it does, use VirtualBox's support for serial port pass-through and tie the virtual device, eg. COM1 to a Host Device and supply the appropriate device path (like /dev/ttyS0) in the text field.

When you restart the virtual machine, you should be able to access the modem from the appropriate /dev/ttySx port starting from 0 = "COM1"